# How to show all swatches of out of product for a configurable products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, swatches

I want to show all swatches of product for out of stock products. Currently it is showing only in stock products.

how to show for out of stocks products.

How to display all swatches

Can someone help me to do this

Advanced thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be able to activate this configuration go to **Products -> Catalog**, there we choose any product and we go to the option of **Quantity**. Under it, there is the option **"advanced inventory"**, click on it and select the first box that says **Use configuration options** found under **Manage stock.**

This configuration will show all the swatches

Comment: This is not worked!!

Comment: Hello @jafarpinjar , please share if you get some solution